# What is wrong with the code?

Tags: c

```
void* myfunction() { 
char *p; 
    *p = 0; 
    return (void*) &p; 
}
```

I know the problem is in the return statement, but it's confusing. Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps p has not been allocated memory yet by you. And *p can be a memory violation.

Comment: You're returning a local variable, this is not good.

Comment: @Peter: Returning the value of a local variable isn't a problem. Returning the *address* of a local variable (as here) is -- your conclusion is correct, but the description of the problem isn't.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks Jerry, I should have been more specific.

Comment: No, it's from a review sheet for a final exam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a problem before the return statement in the `*p = 0;`. You haven't initialized `p`, so this writes to whatever random location that unitialized pointer happens to hold. That gives undefined behavior, so nothing afterwards has any meaningful interpretation at all.

Assuming you fixed that, then yes, the return statement would be a problem as well -- you'd be returning a pointer to data that's destroyed before the return completes, so any attempt at using the pointer you returned would cause undefined behavior again.

Comment: @BloodyHell666, If this answer has helped you solve your problem, then you should accept the answer by clicking on the accept button.